# Product discount calculation verification in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

All I have a query!

I want to ask we have any option in Automation Testing to check discount calculation when a product adds to the cart. Below is the scenario of my question:

Add discounted product to cart
When we go to the checkout page system check price of the product is correct or not according to the percentage of the discount.
If the Price correct then proceed further.
4.Discount is displayed on the website. URL: https://focusclothing.pk/collections/men

My Code is here:

```
WebElement popup_close = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/button")));
popup_close.click();
WebElement sale = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[8]/a")));
         sale.click();
         List<WebElement> product_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[8]/div[1]"));
         
         for (WebElement items_product : product_list) {
             System.out.println(items_product.getText());
         }
         System.out.println("Original Price of Items");
         List<WebElement>  Original_price = driver.findElements(By.className("was"));
         System.out.println(Original_price.size());
         
         for(int i=0; i<Original_price.size(); i++) {
             List<String> Original_price_1st = new ArrayList<String>();
             Original_price_1st.add(Original_price.get(i).getText());
             System.out.println(Original_price.get(i).getText());
             }
         System.out.println("Discounted Price of items");
         List<WebElement> Discounted_price=driver.findElements(By.className("onsale"));
           System.out.println(Discounted_price.size());
           for(int i=0; i<Original_price.size();i++)
           {
                   List<String> Discounted_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
               Discounted_price_lst.add(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
               System.out.println(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
           }
           for(int i=0;i<Discounted_price.size();i++) {
               List<String> Original_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
               List<String> Discounted_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
               String original_price_removecurrencysymbol = Original_price.get(i).getText().substring(3,Original_price.get(i).getText().length());
               String discount_price_removecurrencysymbol = Discounted_price.get(i).getText().substring(3,Discounted_price.get(i).getText().length());
               System.out.println(original_price_removecurrencysymbol);
               System.out.println(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
               
              double difference = Double.valueOf(original_price_removecurrencysymbol) - Double.valueOf(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
              System.out.println("Difference is:"+difference);
           }
```

Screenshot of Error I facing:https://prnt.sc/18yvejc
Till there my code find the original prices and discounted prices. Further, I have written the code to find the difference between prices but got an error. After finding the difference between prices I want to check the difference is correct according to the percentage of the discount.

Comment: @cruisepandey : Please reply here.

Comment: Well, you obviously have to write some code to achieve that

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Selenium enables you to investigate the entire DOM which means: yes, you have such an option.

Comment: @Prophet : Can we vote to reopen this question since OP has provided all the details

Comment: @deHaar : Can we vote to reopen this question since OP has provided all the details

Comment: In general, we could... It would be great if OP could provide some decent explanation about his code example: What is it supposed to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: @deHaar I have provided the details of what I want to do. Please have a look at my question and my code.

Comment: @cruisepandey : Can you please tell me what's wrong with this URL: https://prnt.sc/197jtsa

Comment: @cruisepandey : can you share the screenshot of your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you are on the discounted page :

you can use the below code (This code is just for the first web element or image or product that you see on the shared URL):

```
driver.get("https://focusclothing.pk/collections/men-gym-wear");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='price'])[1]/div[@class='onsale']")).getText();
String b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='price'])[1]/div[@class='was']")).getText();
String c = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class = 'sale-item icn'])[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(a +" "+  b +" "+ c);
String[] aa = a.split("\\.");
String[] bb = b.replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
float aaa = Float.parseFloat(aa[1] + "." + aa[2]);
float bbb = Float.parseFloat(bb[1] + "." + bb[2]);
float cc = Float.parseFloat(c.split("\\%")[0]);
float off_cal = bbb - (bbb * cc)/100;
if( off_cal == aaa) {
      System.out.println("matched");
}
```

**Update 1  :**

to get all of them :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://focusclothing.pk/collections/men-gym-wear");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        ArrayList<WebElement> a = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='price']/div[@class='onsale']"));
        ArrayList<WebElement> b = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='price']/div[@class='was']"));
        ArrayList<WebElement> c = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'sale-item icn']"));
        List<Float> aaaa = new ArrayList<Float>() ;
        List<Float> bbbb = new ArrayList<Float>() ;
        List<Float> cccc = new ArrayList<Float>() ;
        System.out.println(a.size() + " " + b.size() + " " + c.size());
        for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++) {
             String[] aaa = a.get(i).getText().replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
             System.out.println(aaa[1] + "." + aaa[2]);
             aaaa.add(Float.parseFloat(aaa[1] + "." + aaa[2]));
             System.out.println(aaaa.get(i));
             
             String[] bbb = b.get(i).getText().replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
             System.out.println(bbb[1] + "." + bbb[2]);
             bbbb.add(Float.parseFloat(bbb[1] + "." + bbb[2]));
             System.out.println(bbbb.get(i));
             
             String[] ccc = c.get(i).getText().split("\\%");
             System.out.println(ccc[0]);
             cccc.add(Float.parseFloat(ccc[0]));
             System.out.println(cccc.get(i));
             
             float off_cal = bbbb.get(i) - (bbbb.get(i)* cccc.get(i))/100;
             if( off_cal == aaaa.get(i)) {
                 System.out.println("matched");
             }
        }
```

**My local machine output  :**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
Test Base Bot has been activated.
Before suite executed successfully
Starting ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}) on port 10675
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1625643389.399][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 91.
Jul 07, 2021 1:06:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
17 17 17
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
matched
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
matched
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
matched
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
matched
1256.50
1256.5
1795.00
1795.0
30
30.0
matched
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
matched
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
matched
1186.50
1186.5
1695.00
1695.0
30
30.0
matched
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
matched
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
matched
1186.50
1186.5
1695.00
1695.0
30
30.0
matched
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
matched
1186.50
1186.5
1695.00
1695.0
30
30.0
matched
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
matched
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
matched
1186.50
1186.5
1695.00
1695.0
30
30.0
matched
1186.50
1186.5
1695.00
1695.0
30
30.0
matched
PASSED: testSO

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
==================================
```

=============

Comment: Great it's working! But if you look at my question I want for all products. Please suggest to me any solution for my code what should I do further.

Comment: @Zaman10 : Check out the updated 1 code above

Comment: Please check the URL of Output of your code: https://prnt.sc/1979jwq is it right, I think it's not, because it does not display all products prices.

Comment: There should b 17 Items on this page and it shows only 2 items' prices.

Comment: no it does not, it shows 17 items if I ran the script on my local. I can show you give you screenshot as well

Comment: 1,357 has `,` in between so I have used replaceAll method. See above how I have dealt with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234602/discussion-between-zaman10-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Can you check above, I have pasted everything from my output console